# Loop en Python eligiendo líneas de un archivo

Tags: python, bucles

Estoy tratando de hacer que Python me busque ciertas líneas (y slices) de un archivo de texto.

El texto es el siguiente (las primeras 60 líneas de 13000):

```
Linea 0     A     213992,"A     114416","05/01/2021","19/01/2021","N","E","1005","*                             "," 0"," 0","   0"," 0"," 0", 
Linea 1     A     114416,"CIOTOLO NORMA TELMA                     ","*                                                 ","POLA 1438                     ","CAPITAL                       ","4682-1534                     "," 74","F","1041","*                                                 ","   0","          ","     ","17/01/2013","17/01/2013","1202","15052545070100                ","DNI", 
Linea 2     C,"3755162        ","01/05/1938","*                             ","2","*      ", 
Linea 3     G   
Linea 4     A     213992,"            ","            ","                    ","                    ","                    ", 
Linea 5     13
Linea 6      1      475I 1
Linea 7      2      941I 1
Linea 8      3      190I 1
Linea 9      4      192I 1
Linea 10     5      412I 1
Linea 11     6     4811I 1
Linea 12     7      865I 1
Linea 13     8      867I 1
Linea 14     9      902I 1
Linea 15    10     8298I 1
Linea 16    11      546I 1
Linea 17    12      711I 1
Linea 18    13      120N 1
Linea 19    A     213993,"A     129320","05/01/2021","12/01/2021","N","E","1005","*                             "," 0"," 0","   0"," 0"," 0", 
Linea 20    A     129320,"LOPREITO ALICIA MIRTA                   ","*                                                 ","PIEDRABUENA 3841              ","CAPITAL                       ","4601-5620  1150631906         "," 73","F","   0","DNI 5694842                                       ","   0","          ","     ","05/01/2021","05/01/2021","1005","15046761690600                ","DNI", 
Linea 21    C,"5694842        ","11/10/1947","*                             ","2","*      ", 
Linea 22    G   
Linea 23    A     213993,"            ","            ","                    ","                    ","                    ", 
Linea 24    12
Linea 25     1      475I 1
Linea 26     2      653I 1
Linea 27     3      746I 1
Linea 28     4      133I 1
Linea 29     5      192I 1
Linea 30     6      362I 1
Linea 31     7      412I 1
Linea 32     8     4811I 1
Linea 33     9      546I 1
Linea 34    10      902I 1
Linea 35    11      948I 1
Linea 36    12      120N 1
Linea 37    A     214012,"A     129321","04/01/2021","18/01/2021","N","E","1005","*                             "," 0"," 0","   0"," 0"," 0", 
Linea 38    A     129321,"SERRANO MARIA DOLORES                   ","*                                                 ","LARRAZABAL 1551               ","CAPITAL                       ","1123101950                    "," 86","F","   0","DNI 16561081                                      ","   0","          ","     ","04/01/2021","04/01/2021","1005","15053746050100                ","DNI", 
Linea 39    C,"16561081       ","02/03/1934","*                             ","2","*      ", 
Linea 40    G   
Linea 41    A     214012,"            ","            ","                    ","                    ","                    ", 
Linea 42    11
Linea 43     1      475I 1
Linea 44     2      192I 1
Linea 45     3      297I 1
Linea 46     4      412I 1
Linea 47     5     4811I 1
Linea 48     6      546I 1
Linea 49     7      865I 1
Linea 50     8      866I 1
Linea 51     9      867I 1
Linea 52    10      500I 1
Linea 53    11     8298I 1
Linea 54    A     214013,"A     125271","04/01/2021","13/01/2021","N","E","1005"," 136                          "," 0"," 0","   0"," 0"," 0", 
Linea 55    A     125271,"IMPRENTA MIGUEL ARTURO                  ","*                                                 ","P.GARCIA 5887                 ","CAPITAL                       ","4605-5813                     "," 69","M"," 136","DNI 6151369                                       ","   0","          ","     ","27/10/2017","27/10/2017","1005","15060320150300                ","DNI", 
Linea 56    C,"6151369        ","01/11/1948","*                             ","2","*      ", 
Linea 57    G   
Linea 58    A     214013,"            ","            ","                    ","                    ","                    ", 
Linea 59    2
Linea 60     1      412I 1
Linea 61     2      500I 1
```

Debe tomar información de las líneas 0,1 y 2

que debería dar este resultado:

```
DATA
CIATTLO MARIA TELMA;DNI;3666162;;;;;;;;;;01/05/1900;F;;;05/01/2021;158888450701;00;;;;;;;;
```

El código hasta acá es:

```
with open ("E:\Test.txt", "r") as f:

     linea = f.readlines()



     def persona(linea):


      data = []                       # Lista con los campos a mostrar en una línea
      data.append(linea[1][16:49].rstrip())         # Nombre y Apellido
      data.append(linea[1][375:378])                # Tipo Documento
      data.append(linea[2][5:20].replace(" ", ""))  # Nro Documento
      data.append(";;;;;;;;")
      data.append(linea[2][23:33])                  # Fecha de Nacimiento
      data.append(linea[1][217:218])                # Sexo
      data.append(";")
      data.append(linea[0][31:41])                  # fecha
      data.append(linea[1][342:354])                # Beneficio
      data.append(linea[1][354:356])                # Parentesco
      data.append(";;;;;;;")
  
      print(";".join(data))

print("DATA") 
persona(linea)
```

No se como hacer para que luego agregue la misma información de las líneas 19, 20 y 21, y de la 37, 38 y 39 y así sucesivamente delas 13000 líneas del archivo.

La clave para saber cuales son las siguientes 3 líneas a leer es la suma del valor de la línea 5 (en este caso 13) + 6 (que son las líneas con información).
El resultado para este ejemplo seria:

```
DATA
CIATTLO MARIA TELMA;DNI;3666162;;;;;;;;;;01/05/1900;F;;;05/01/2021;158888450701;00;;;;;;;;
LOPEZITO ALACIA MIRNA;DNI;5688842;;;;;;;;;;11/10/1900;F;;;05/01/2021;150646464906;00;;;;;;;;
SICRANO MARIA DOLORES;DNI;16001081;;;;;;;;;;02/03/1900;F;;;04/01/2021;150538888501;00;;;;;;;;
IMPARNTA MIGUEL ARTURO;DNI;6152269;;;;;;;;;;01/11/1900;M;;;04/01/2021;150669691503;00;;;;;;;;
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Las palabras `Linea 0`, `Linea 1`, etc ¿son para ilustrar o están incluidas en el archivo?

Comment: Mirando la línea 37 parece que los espacios al comienzo no son relevantes, ¿correcto?

Comment: Si, las palabras Linea 0... son ilustrativas y a partir de la Linea 10 mueven espacios en la lista. En el archivo esto no existe, todas las lineas estan sobre el margen izquierdo. Ahi esta corregido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Y si tratas el archivo como un CSV?
En esta sugerencia, se convierte cada línea en CSV separado por `,`

```
import csv

with open('test.txt') as csvfile:
    csvdata = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    data = []
    sublist = []
    i = 1
    for row in csvdata:
        #print(', '.join(row))
        if (len(row) > 1):
            if (i%4 != 0):
                sublist.extend(row)
            else:
                data.append(sublist)
                sublist = []
            i += 1
```

Se recorre cada línea descartando las que tienen un elemento o menos, quedando 4 líneas por cada entrada.

Por cada ciclo se hace un extend sublist cada 4 lineas. Al llegar a la 4ta `(i%4 == 0)` se hace *append* de la lista `data` y se reinicia `sublist`.

Una vez se termina el ciclo se tiene una lista con sublistas en `data`. Si hicieras un `print(data)`, obtendrías algo así:

```
[
    ['A     213992', 'A     114416', ..., '114416', 'CIOTOLO NORMA TELMA  ', ...], 
    ['A     213993', 'A     129320', ..., '129320', 'LOPREITO ALICIA MIRTA  ', ...],
    ...
]
```

Ya tienes todos los registros dentro de la variable `data`. Ahora ya es solo cuestión de buscar los items requeridos en cada sublista:

```
for row in data:
    fnac = row[2].strip()
    name = row[15].strip()
    sexo = row[21].strip()
    num = row[30].strip()
    benef = num[:-2]
    paren = num[-2:]
    tdoc = row[31]
    dni = row[34].strip()
    fecha = row[35].strip()
    print(f'{name};{tdoc};{dni};;;;;;;;;;{fecha};{sexo};;;{fnac};{benef};{paren};;;;;;;;')
```

Comment: Hola, me encanto la simplicidad (cuanto me falta aprender... me estoy dando de cabeza contra la pared). Muy buena idea tratarlo como lo que es: un csv... Muchisimas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Primero, las funciones conviene definirlas al nivel más externo, por lo que moví la función `persona` fuera del ciclo principal. La función no tiene cambios.

Para procesos de este tipo no se ocupa `readlines()`. Esta función intenta leer todo el archivo y convertirlo en una lista, lo cual es lento, ineficaz y puede causar una caida por falta de memoria.

Lo que se usa para archivos masivos, y en general para cualquier proceso donde tengas que sacar cuentas, como acá, es la función `readline()`, que sólo lee una línea cada vez.

Entonces, el proceso se resume en:

- Leer tres líneas de datos interesantes.
- Procesarlas.
- Leer otras tres líneas para llegar al valor a saltar.
- Leer y descartar tantas líneas como dijo el valor leido.
- Repetir hasta el fin de archivo.

No está claro como termina el archivo. Para estos efectos, supondre que está marcado con un `salto == 0`

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    while True:
        #
        # Leer tres lineas de data
        #
        lineas = []
        for i in range(3):
            lineas.append(f.readline())
        #
        # Procesar las tres lineas
        #
        persona(lineas)
        #
        # Ubicar la línea con el valor del salto
        #
        for i in range(3):
            linea = f.readline()
        salto = int(linea)
        if salto == 0:
            break
        #
        # Saltar el número de líneas indicadas
        #
        for i in range(salto):
            f.readline()
```

produce:

```
"CIOTOLO NORMA TELMA;"DN;"3755162;;;;;;;;;;"01/05/193;";;;"05/01/202;"15052545070;10;;;;;;;;
"LOPREITO ALICIA MIRTA;"DN;"5694842;;;;;;;;;;"11/10/194;";;;"05/01/202;"15046761690;60;;;;;;;;
"SERRANO MARIA DOLORES;"DN;"16561081;;;;;;;;;;"02/03/193;";;;"04/01/202;"15053746050;10;;;;;;;;
"IMPRENTA MIGUEL ARTURO;"DN;"6151369;;;;;;;;;;"01/11/194;";;;"04/01/202;"15060320150;30;;;;;;;;
```

Teniendo ya las líneas, puedes ajustar la salida al formato que desees.

Comment: Gracias, si, la funcion persona debe ir afuera del proceso, yo la puse para poder saber que la líneas que sacaba estaban bien. El proceso funciona bien, pero me arroja al final:
`;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; `
como que esta leyendo una línea demás, porque el archivo termina como si la Linea 62 existiera en blanco. Gracias.

Comment: Si, a mi también. Le puse un salto = 0 para marcar el fin de archivo. Esa parte tienes que ajustarla.

Comment: Gracias, veo como ajustarlo, fue de mucha ayuda!!!